# Why does Primavera P6 EPPM REST API version 2112 not allow access to Spread REST Endpoints?

Tags: java, rest, weblogic, primavera

I'm developing a Java application to extract data from Oracle Primavera P6 EPPM 2112 by using the P6 EPPM REST API.

I installed Weblogic, Primavera P6 EPPM version 21.12 with P6 WebServices, Microsoft SQL Server and loaded project data provided by customer.

Everything is working fine and my Java application can get Project, WBS and Activity data through P6 EPPM REST API, the problem is that I need to load spread information but **all Spread REST endpoints don't exists in my server**. These Spread endpoints are available in P6 WebServices (SOAP) but not in the REST API service.

I searched on Oracle's P6 EPPM REST API website documentation and the Spread REST endpoints are available with all other endpoints:

[P6 EPPM Rest API - Spread REST Endpoints](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/F37125_01/English/Integration_Documentation/rest_api/api-spread.html)

I have read all available P6 EPPM 2112 related documentation and searched online for this issue without success. I also posted a question on Oracle Communities website but still without answer.

Is there any additional configuration I must do in order to enable these Spread endpoints or are they only available in newer P6 EPPM versions?

In short, why Spread REST endpoints are not available on my P6 EPPM 2112 server?

I installed the full P6 package on three different machines (2 Windows 10 desktop clients and 1 Windows Server machine) to see if I made a mistake in the installation process, but Spread REST endpoints are not available on any of these installations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I didn't get any response and I couldn't find any solution, I updated the Primavera environment to version 22.12. After this update, all endpoints are now available.

Comment: @SknetAdmin - I am facing a similar problem accessing the spread service endpoints specifically ResourceAssignmentSpread to pull data but getting bad request. I am able to retrieve other service eg. Project, Activites..etc. I have also checked version which is 23.1.0. Have you any pointers on URL besides their documentation